# Jquery 2.1.1 & Lightbox Conflict

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, lightbox

I want to have a photo upload and a lightbox in one page but when i coded it i have a conflict with my jquery-2.1.1 and lightbox js. Tried to use jQuery.conflict(); instead of solving my problem, another one arises "jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function".

my original code is this one.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>`

<a href='assets/uploads/" . $v['path'] ."' data-lightbox='image-". $v['path'] ."'>

echo "<a href='assets/uploads/" . $v['path'] ."' data-lightbox='image-". $v['path'] ."'>
     <img style='width: 200px;' class='example-image' src='assets/uploads/" .$v['path'] ."' alt='img-1'>
</a>";

<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='php/exec/add-collection-exec.php' style="clear:both">
    <div id='imageloadstatus'><img src="assets/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/></div>
    <div id='imageloadbutton'>
        <div class='file-field input-field'>
            <div class='btn'>
                <span>Image</span>
                <input type="file" name="file[]" id="photoimg" multiple="true"/>
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  lightbox.option({
    'resizeDuration': 1,
    'wrapAround': true,
    'fitImagesInViewport' : true,
    'disableScrolling' : true
  })


      $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#photoimg').on('change', function(){
      var A=$("#imageloadstatus");
      var B=$("#imageloadbutton");
      $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: "#preview",
        beforeSubmit:function(){
          A.show();
          B.hide();
        },
        success:function(){
          A.hide();
          B.show();
          location.assign("uploads.php");
        },
        error:function(){
          A.hide();
          B.show();
        } 
        }).submit();
    }); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your link first 
**From**

```
<a href='assets/uploads/" . $v['path'] ."' data-lightbox='image-". $v['path'] ."'>

echo "<a href='assets/uploads/" . $v['path'] ."' data-lightbox='image-". $v['path'] ."'>
     <img style='width: 200px;' class='example-image' src='assets/uploads/" .$v['path'] ."' alt='img-1'>
</a>";
```

**To**

```
echo "<a href='assets/uploads/" . $v['path'] ."' data-lightbox='image-". $v['path'] ."'>
          <img style='width: 200px;' class='example-image' src='assets/uploads/" .$v['path'] ."' alt='img-1'>
      </a>";
```

And dont need to add your `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` because `lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js` already has jquery, of course adding another jquery in your page will result to **`two jquery`** that conflicts to each other.The thing that you can do is put all your jquery code at the bottom part of your page after the `lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js`. Here's a simple example from [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lightbox Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css">
</head>
<body>

  <section>
    <h3>Click me to check if jquery is working</h3>
    <div>
      <a class="example-image-link" 
         href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-1.jpg" 
         data-lightbox="example-1">

         <img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-1.jpg" alt="image-1" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <h3>Click me to check if jquery is working</h3>
    <div>
      <a class="example-image-link" 
          href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-3.jpg" 
          data-lightbox="example-set" 
          data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward.">
          <img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("h3").click(function(){
          alert(1);
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering, because `lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js` includes jQuery. I think, there's no need to include `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` before.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried to remove it a while ago and my scripts are all undefined.

Comment: did you try lightbox.min.js instead?